# How do I get Crash and Ratings statistics for my apps on App Store

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

I am trying to fetch crash and ratings statistics from App Store connect API but there doesn't seem to be a way. I searched similar statistics for google play apps and was able to find a cloud storage bucket where google just dumps all the stats for all apps as csv files. Is there some API endpoint in App Store Connect that I'm missing or maybe some other service where I can find all these stats?